Recording individual legs of a Twilio conference
I need to record each individual leg of a Twilio conference because, in our domain, it's important that each participant has access to a recording of the conference as they heard it, e.g. User A can't hear things that User B and User C said while User A was on hold, etc.
From the Twilio docs, however, I can only see a way of recording the entire conference in one mixed mono recording (or a dual recording where the first person in is one track and everyone else is mixed into the other).
I've tried posting to https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{callSid}/Recordings.json with the individual call leg SID but it seems the resulting recording is still just a mixed recording of the entire conference.
How can I accomplish what I need?
